# Rails JQuery Ajax: refreshing table row throwing 404 error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a table of order_items where each order_item is represented on a table row with a button to "set_aside". The goal is to execute the set_aside controller action for an individual order item and refresh only that table row with an updated table row that contains the new status of the order_item.

The controller action:

**order_items_controller.rb**

```
def set_aside
  @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

My **set_aside.js.erb** is:

```
$('#<%= @order_item.id %>').load("<%= j render 'admin/shipments/packing_item_row.haml', locals: {i: @order_item, index: 1} %>");
$('#<%= @order_item.id %>').show();
```

The view is `admin/shipments/packing.haml` and contains a table where each table row of the instance variable `@order_items` is rendered as the partial "packing_item_row" and all table rows have id set.

*Here's where I am stuck:*

Using the `.load()` function keeps on throwing an error that I can see in Web Inspector/XHR.

Web Inspector shows that the set_aside action correctly includes the order_item.id and the associated HTML in the render call. But then there is a second XHR query that throws a 404 status error by trying to load a `admin/shipments/%3Ctr%3E%Ctd` resource as well.

Subbing in the .html method seems to load the partial just fine, so it's not a matter of the partial having faulty locals passed in. But the load function simply doesn't seem to work and I am not sure what else to try at this point.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why this doesn't work

It looks from the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/) that `load()` accepts a URL, whereas you're giving it some HTML.

So that means it's trying to access a URL that's the return value of the HTML.

That, I suspect, is where the `admin/shipments/%3Ctr%3E%Ctd` URL is coming from.

The `%3Ctr%3E%Ctd` gobbledegook is Rails returning the HTML to jQuery.

jQuery in turn is trying to make sense of it as a URL. `<` encoded is `%3C` - it's taking the start of the first table in your view.

### Why can't you use `html()`?

It's the easiest way and tried and tested in this scenario. If there's a good reason you don't want to use `html()`...

### How to use `load()`

If you really want to use load you'll need to create a route for this partial rendering.

If the route is called `admin_shipments_packing_item_path` you'd do something like:

`$('#<%= @order_item.id %>').load("<%= j admin_shipments_packing_item_path(@order_item) %>");`

Any more questions, just ask!

Comment: Thank you -- this clears it up! I ended up going the .html route and things are working very nicely!